# PHP Comparing a date to todays date

Tags: php, date

I am trying to take a credit card expiry date in the format of `mm-yy` and see if that date has passed so I know if the credit card has expired. If it has expired, a class of `expired` is inserted on the `<tr>`

My code results in a sample date of 05/16 being checked, and the script says that the card has not expired when obviously this card is a year old.

```
<?php foreach($card_historys as $card_history){ 
    $expired = "";
    $date = strtotime($card_history->expire); //Returns a date in mm/yy
    $noww = strtotime(date('m/y'));

    echo "expire: ".$date." / now: ".$noww."<br>";

    if($date < $noww){$expired = 'expired';}
  ?>
  <tr class="<?php echo $expired; ?>">
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: we cannot reproduce when we do not know contents of your variables; so user `var_export`. Also show code that actually is running; this has syntax errors.

Comment: Which variables are you unsure sure about? The only variable not set in the snippet is $card_history->expire which I have mentioned is mm/yy

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2167916/convert-one-date-format-into-another-in-php?noredirect=1&lq=1

Check this

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When using PHP's built in date functionality, you need to make sure you are using a [valid datetime format](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php). Otherwise `strtotime()` will return `false` and `DateTime()` will throw an exception.

To work with non-standard datetime formats you can use [`DateTime::createFromFormat()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) to parse the datetime string and return a [`DateTime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) object from which you can [get a Unix Timestamp](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.gettimestamp.php), [convert the date into another format](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php), or use it to compare to other `DateTime` objects.

```
// Date separated by dots
$date01 = \DateTime::createFromFormat('Y.m.d', '2017.04.18');

// Date with no separator
$date02 = \DateTime::createFromFormat('Ymd', '20170418');

// Get Unix timestamp
$timestamp = $date01->getTimestamp();

// Get MySQL format (ISO-8601)
$mysqlDate = $date02->format('Y-m-d');
```

So for your issue, you would do the following:

```
$expires = \DateTime::createFromFormat('m/y', $card_history->expire);
$today   = new \DateTime();

if($expires < $today){$expired = 'expired';}
```

**See also:**

- [Convert one date format into another in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2167916/convert-one-date-format-into-another-in-php)
- [Compare DateTime objects with comparison operators in PHP](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/PHP/Data_Types/DateTime/Compare_DateTime_objects_with_comparison_operators_in_PHP.htm)